# How to generate local variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When writting codes, if we typed a undefined references, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> will bring up the generating-code list box which says generate field/property/method. I'm looking for a way to generate a local variable but I don't know how to.

To make it more clearer, I'll give an example.
Say we have a method

```
void MyMethod(MyType param)
{
    //do something
}
```

Then in another method of the same class I write:

```
MyMethod(undefinedObject);
```

I wish to be able to generate the below codes automatically (of course through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> when placing the cursor under 'undefinedObject'):

```
var undefinedObject = new MyType();
MyMethod(undefinedObject);
```

Hope you have some work-around for me. Thanks!

[Edit]
At the moment, I use the generated field. Then cut the line declaring the field and paste it on the line where it should be in my code. This routine is time-consuming and quite boring. So I ask here to look for a better way/addon to do that. Prefer a free tool, not Resharper I hope.

Comment: "This routine is time-consuming and quite boring" - why not just define your variables as you go, then?

Comment: @Marc: I think it's my habit - calling the method first and then fill in the parameters. It's just a thought: since the editor can get the type of the parameter, I don't want to do that myself and save my though on the business logic only.

Comment: well, yes; but the editor can't infer what the *value* should be, and once you know what you want as the *value*, declaring it can be as simple as adding `var x=` to the side of that...

Comment: @Marc: I agree. The generated variables should be reviewed to fill in the actual value for the object.

Answer (score 1):

Resharper will offer this via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: I think he is looking for how to create an MEF component that can be installed and such code can be extended.

Comment: @Akash: Where do you see the op mentioning about *writing a component* or of *extensibility*?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 offers MEF (Managed Extendibility Framework) in which you can create your own context menu extension after installing Visual Studio 2010 SDK, and you can write your code, it will not be very easy and straight forward, but you can look into SDK documentation and samples offered by SDK, you will get some idea of how to customize and create custom behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to [create](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984) your own or [edit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984) an existing **`Method Stub - Body`** snippet that comes with Visual Studio. You can access it via *Tools-->Refactoring* menu option.

You may require:

1. A [Snippet Editor](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=snippeteditor)
2. A manual step by step [Howto](https://web.archive.org/web/20120527173754/http://en.csharp-online.net/Visual_Studio_Code_Snippets%E2%80%94Creating_Snippets_Manually)

Also, [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140520044600/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2005/12/08/501763.aspx) may help.